# Looping through a JSON return, from API call, and rendering as HTML with Ruby and Sinatra

Tags: ruby, json, rest

I am using the Plivo API. When I do a phone number search. I get this returned in the terminal:

```
{"stock"=>1,
     "voice_enabled"=>true,
     "region"=>"New York, UNITED STATES",
     "voice_rate"=>"0.00900",
     "prefix"=>"212",
     "sms_rate"=>"0.00800",
     "number_type"=>"local",
     "setup_rate"=>"0.00000",
     "rental_rate"=>"0.80000",
     "group_id"=>"29753262281573",
     "sms_enabled"=>true,
     "resource_uri"=>
      "/v1/Account/MAZDQ1ZJIYMDZKMMZKYM/AvailableNumberGroup/29753262281573/"}
```

How can I loop through it and render as HTML to get a result like this:

```
<div>
<ul>
<li>
Region: json_obj['region']
</li>
<li>
Prefix: json_obj['prefix']
</li>
and so on ...
</ul>
```

The plivo gem facilitates getting the returned object with:

```
obj = response.last
```

I have tried:

```
obj = response.last
@region = obj['region']
```

followed by:

```
<%= @region %>
```

which produces an error message to say that object or method does not exist, or just nothing.

My ruby code is:

```
get '/search' do
    erb :search
end
```

and

```
get '/search/data' do
    country_iso = params[:country_iso]
    region = params[:region]
    prefix = params[:prefix]
    p = RestAPI.new(AUTH_ID, AUTH_TOKEN)
    params = {'country_iso' => country_iso, 'region' => region, 'prefix' => prefix}
    #warn params.inspect
    response = p.get_number_group(params)
    pp response
    obj = response.last
    @region = obj['region']
    @prefix = obj['prefix']
    erb :search
end
```

The terminal shows me that the params are passed correctly from the ajax call and the desired number search takes place, I just cannot print the json response out in nice HTML.

Should erb :search appear twice as above or just once? On the search.erb page there is a dropdown and input boxes to collect the parameters, that all works fine.

Sorry it's so long. To summarise: how can I render a json response in nice HTML and am I getting confused about my erb pages with the two ruby segments above?

Comment: are you sure you are getting that response in an obj as this is working nicely http://codepad.org/H7WT4brc

Comment: That looks great, but .... where do I put this 
puts obj['region']
puts obj['prefix'] ? In the get '/search/data' do section? 

Then, what code goes on the erb :search page to render the response?

That's (an important part) part of the problem! Thank you.



And then what code do I need to write on the erb :search to render the result?

Comment: It "puts" it in the terminal, what do I need to do to "put" it in HTML on search.erb? That's half the difficulty for me!

Comment: This is what appears in the terminal:

[200,
 {"meta"=>
   {"previous"=>nil,
    "total_count"=>36,
    "offset"=>0,
    "limit"=>1,
    "next"=>
     "/v1/Account/MAZDQ1ZJIYMDZKMMZKYM/AvailableNumberGroup/?prefix=415&limit=1&country_iso=US&region=California&offset=1"},
  "api_id"=>"b2fff2d2-bd3b-11e2-aed1-22000ac413e7",
  "objects"=>
   [{"stock"=>50,
     "voice_enabled"=>true,
     "region"=>"California, UNITED STATES",
     "voice_rate"=>"0.00900",
     ,
     "group_id"=>"11569714026792",
     "sms_enabled"=>true,
     "resource_uri"=>
     }]}]

Comment: Yes, I am getting the response in an obj. I tried: 

 obj = response.last
    pp obj

and it  printed to the object fine (in the terminal). So my problem is still how to get it on the the HTML page. Are my ruby segments above wrong? Perhaps the clue is there.

Comment: Still stuck. I copied everything on codepad and still could not get a print out. So I included this on my page: <%= obj['region'] %> and, predictably, got an error message.

Comment: ohhh....very sorry for the late response..stuck with the prj..let me know if u still need help

Comment: you are right I am getting no response: pp response.last returns nil. Previously response last returned a value, so I really am stuck now.

Comment: let me chk the Pilvo API first..so that i can help u further

Comment: try removing this line "pp response" and then chk..I believe this one is for console(haven't used this pretty print though till) and check if u included by require 'pp'

Comment: obj = response.last
pp response.last
prints the entire json hash but
     pp obj['region'] returns nil

Comment: code is working fine at my end http://i.imgur.com/0DtNmHI.jpg

Comment: pp is included. I tried as you said but no difference. pp obj['objects'] prints the whole thing but pp obj['obects']['region'] produces an error and same for pp obj['region']

Comment: thank yow. How do you then print it as html? I still don't get that part, I am afraid. And I still can't get it printed on my console with pp obj['region']. I can print the entire obj but not one element which is what I need.

Comment: I should add "thank you for the time you have spent on this"! I appreciate it.

Comment: No..if still not solve I can help u further..was at my way to home now

Comment: Hi swapnesh. We are still not there, I am afraid. Some issues: 1) puts only seems to work in the terminal, not on the html page. 2) whatever I do only works in the terminal not on the html page, so obj = response.last pp obj (or puts) obj prints the obj in the terminal but any attempts to reference it for, html purposes, like @region = obj['region'] or region = obj['region'] fail and cause an error message on the server. Please remember too, that you are testing with a static object, I think, whereas my object comes from an api call.

Comment: One more  update: the following puts in the terminal

obj["objects"].each{|p| puts p["voice_rate"] }  but <%= obj["objects"].each{|p| puts p["voice_rate"] } %> gives an error message on search.erb. Just to repeat, my real problem is how to render the obj as HTML.

Comment: SOLVED!! obj = response.last
      @voice_rate = obj["objects"][0]["voice_rate"]
Thank you swapnesh fro your patience.

Comment: oh WoW...g8..thx for making we aware of the solution ..will keep in mind :)

Comment: Please put answers into an answer. Please put clarifications for the question into the question. Comments may be deleted at any time.